# STS shows errors with a clean new maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin

STS is showing an "useless" error when trying to create a new project. I did chose to ignore it and it did not cause any issues with the build , however just to nitpick , I would like to find a way to fix this error. 
[image]

I have already tried setting the maven configurations within Eclipse and it still doesnt work.

Comment: It says _"Maven Configuration Problem"_, so show your Maven configuration. Is this the current version of Eclipse/STS/M2E?

Comment: This can happen with maven plugins which are not compatible. Google that please.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the embedded Maven within STS container. On changing the maven directory preferences within STS albeit to one running an older version solved the issue.